# Using the List Feature in Python

Tags: python

```
month_days= [('January',[31]),('February',[28,29]),('March',[31]),

('April',[30]),('May',[31]),('June',[30]),('July',[31]),('August',[31]),

('September',[30]),('October',[31]),('November',[30]),('December',[31]) ]

day_names = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
```

**Problem 1**
Write a function days_in_month which takes a month as an argument and finds the corresponding month in the month_days list and returns the number of days associated with that month.

Comment: We don't do your homework. You have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: *"Write a ..."* - Ordering us to do something is rather rude.

Comment: Oh sorry youre right it is my home work, it seems like im ordering you cause i copy and pasted the entire question. I tried attempting it but.. I feel as if what i have is not what the examiners is looking for. The following is my fourth attempt. One i believed would be a guaranteed way of getting results but something about it feels missing, besides the point the code is not completed but. Something is not being used her. Idk


def days_in_month(month_days):
    if month_days == 'January' or 'March' or 'May' or 'July' or 'August' or 'October' or 'December':
        return month_days [31]

Comment: @javierkid Edit your question and put your code attempt in the question and use the formatting tools to format it properly. Then explain why the code is not working. Had you done this from the beginning, your question would have been much better received and you would have gotten a quicker more relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def days_in_month(month):
    for m, nblist in month_days:
        if month==m:
            return nblist
    else:
        return []


days_in_month('May')
Out[20]: [31]

days_in_month('Mady')
Out[21]: []
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice Pythonic approach would to be to create a dictionary out of that list using a dictionary comprehension. It would look something like this:

```
month_days_dict = { key:val for (key, val) in month_days }
```

and then you can easily access the value for 'January' for example by saying:

```
month_days_dict['January']
```

however, I suggest you at least try to figure your homework out before posting ;)

Comment: A better I idea would be to avoid answering questions such as this one altogether as it is simply a _"feed me a hunk of code!"_ question and should/will be closed accordingly.

Comment: Well I didn't implement the function at least I just gave a Python-specific approach. But rest assured, he got my downvote ;)

Comment: An easier way to make that `dict` out of that `month_days` is `dict(month_days)`.

Comment: Ah nice didn't notice that. Lol glad I posted thanks!